# Changing the image source depending on the parent link?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I've looked into Javascript for this solution but I'm afraid my knowledge for this is just too limited. I'm guessing the solution to this issue would have to be solved with "nodes" but I just can't wrap my mind around *how*...

I'm looking to bypass image removal on the following website by changing the image source.
[Website link](http://www.last.fm/music/King+Crimson/+albums)

```
<a href="/music/King+Crimson/In+the+Court+of+the+Crimson+King" class="g3 album-item-cover link-hook" itemprop="url">
   <div class="cover-image  cover-image--no-content" style="background-image: url('http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/responsive/2/noimage/default_album_300_g4.png');">
      <img class="cover-image-image" src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/responsive/2/noimage/default_album_300_g4.png" alt="" />
      <div class="text-over-image ">
         <span class="text-over-image-text">In the Court of the Crimson King</span>
         <br/>
         <span class="text-over-image-text text-over-image-text--secondary">148,881 listeners</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

Now I've tried very basic functions like 'replace.' but I got no results for that. Is there a way to change the following,using JavaScript, depending on the URL at the top of the code?

Example:

```
<a href="/music/King+Crimson/URL-A">
...
<img class="cover-image-image" src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/responsive/2/noimage/default_album_300_g4.png" alt="" />
...
</a>

<a href="/music/King+Crimson/URL-B">
...
<img class="cover-image-image" src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/responsive/2/noimage/default_album_300_g4.png" alt="" />
...
</a>
```

Into:

```
<a href="/music/King+Crimson/URL-A">
...
<img class="cover-image-image" src="COVERFORA.JPG" alt="" />
...
</a>

<a href="/music/King+Crimson/URL-B">
...
<img class="cover-image-image" src="COVERFORB.JPG" alt="" />
...
</a>
```

I apologize for the little material I'm offering myself but I'm just wondering if there's actually a solution to this.
Thanks for taking the time to read this post.

Cheers!

Edit:

A few examples of the source code from the following website: http://www.last.fm/music/King+Crimson/+albums

```
<a href="/music/King+Crimson/In+the+Court+of+the+Crimson+King"    class="g3 album-item-cover link-hook" itemprop="url">
    <img src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/responsive/2/noimage/default_album_300_g4.png" alt="Album cover for In the Court of the Crimson King" class="rounded" width="220" height="220" />
</a>

<a href="/music/King+Crimson/Red"    class="g3 album-item-cover link-hook" itemprop="url">
    <img src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/responsive/2/noimage/default_album_300_g4.png" alt="Album cover for Red" class="rounded" width="220" height="220" />
</a>
```

Now, the idea is to insert my own image sources into each of these but obviously it's trickier because all of the links have the same image as default.

Comment: Are the links and imgs being pulled dynamically?  If so, how?  You could probably just do it all at the time that you pull that info.

Comment: And could you give a couple of *real* URLs? Because I don't think that the `href` of `/music/King+Crimson/URL-A` influencing the `src` to become `COVERFORA.JPG` really conveys the complexity of the task. Unless the `src` really *is* `coverfor` + `last-letter-of-href + `.jpg``?

Comment: I added some examples above, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, and what do you want the relevant `src` of those examples to become, based on the posted `href`s?

Comment: Well, as an example I'd use <img src="http://blog.sme.sk/blog/130/10281/clanok_foto.jpg" alt="Album cover for In The Court Of The Crimson King /> instead of the default one in the source code.

Comment: @user1687320 please explain the procedure to get to `"blog.sme.sk/blog/130/10281/clanok_foto.jpg"` from `"/music/King+Crimson/In+the+Court+of+the+Crimson+King"` (i.e. your transformation). I would then be able to improve my answer. If it is a hard-coded dictionary, you will need to write each item manually yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, for each hyperlink on that webpage I'd have to state where the new image source is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to do

```
var albumCover = document.querySelectorAll('.g3.album-item-cover.link-hook'), // get all links
    i = albumCover.length,
    a, img,
    dict = {  // link dictionary, href : src
        '/music/King+Crimson/In+the+Court+of+the+Crimson+King' : 'http://photobucket.com/InTheCourt.jpg',
        '/music/King+Crimson/Discipline' : 'http://photobucket.com/Discipline.jpg'
    };
while( --i >= 0 ) {                         // loop over each link
    a = albumCover[i];                      // that link
    img = a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; // that image
    img.src = dict[a.getAttribute('href')]  // replace src on that image based on that link
              || img.src;                   // else no change
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your input, your code changed the images on the webpage to their alt attributes. This is the closest to a result I've seen but what I want to do is the following: Manually give a new source to each of these images, what I tried to use was a 'case'-scenario but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @user1687320, This is because I don't know how you want to transform the _href_ into the _src_, so I did something that produces a _src_ to something that doesn't exist -> `404 Error` -> broken image -> display _alt_

Comment: Ok, now what I'm looking for is some kind of 'if'-code to determine what image should be there, for example:

`if(a===('/music/King+Crimson/In+The+Court+Of+The+Crimson+King')
{img.src='http://photobucket.com/InTheCourt.jpg'}

if (a===('/music/King+Crimson/Discipline')
{img.src='http://photobucket.com/Discipline.jpg'}`

But with code that would actually be correctly written ;).

Comment: @user1687320 as these are strings it is faster do this using an object than a list of `if..else` or `switch..case`. See my edit.

Comment: That did the trick! I can't thank you enough for your help on this one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.album-item-cover > img.rounded'​).each(function(e) {
    var $this=$(this);
    $this.attr('src',this.parentElement.href
                          .replace(/^.*\/([^\/]+)$/,'Cover_for-$1.jpg'));
    }
    )​​​​​;
```

`$1` here is string after last /